# Spotfire - point to data with input date and comparison to today

Tags: spotfire

My issue is kind of tricky but I'll try to explain it as clearly as possible.
I have an ID with an update date and a value.

I would like to create a fonctionnality which allows users to input a date and point to the corresponding sum of values corresponding to the update.

Here is an example of the data :

| ID | Value | Update date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 01 | 100 | 01/01/2019 |
| 01 | 200 | 15/10/2021 |
| 02 | 800 | 01/01/2019 |
| 03 | 400 | 16/10/2020 |

If the user inputs 20/10/2022 for instance, he should get the sum of rows 2,3 and 4.
If the user inputs 10/01/2019, he should get the sum of rows 1 and 3.

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't say in which form you want this result. I am going to guess you want a single calculated value.

Try adding a *Text area*, then edit it and add a *Calculated Value*.

Given the small example provided, this worked. Set it up as below.

In the *Data* tab, type the *Limit data using expression*:

```
case when [Update date]<=Date('${myDate}') then [Update date]=Max([Update date]) over [ID] end
```

where ${myDate} is a document property you will have set up to contain your cutoff date.

In the *Values* tab select:

```
Sum(Value)
```

This should give you the sum of the maximum value of [Update date] for each ID, after filtering by the cutoff date.

Comment: Thanks a lot ! That works.

This implies that I input a value in the document property. 
Is there any way we can allow the user to dynamically input a value in this document property so the value changes ?

Many thanks,

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by dynamically? If you mean some kind of automation, maybe this should be a separate question?

Comment: Currently, I, as a designer, input a value in the document property. Can the customer input a value himself in order to do his own analysis ?

Comment: If you set up a text area, with an input field connected to a document property, the user can input values into the document property that way.

Comment: Wonderful ! I didn't know about this functionality. Thanks for taking the time.